# Assert verify that mocked object receives expected exception

Tags: c#, .net, moq

If I'm getting expected NotImplementedException on my mock object how can I assert verify that behavior is expected.

```
[Test]
var hoteServiceMock = ...
...
hotelServiceMock
                .Setup(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<HotelToCreateDTO>(), true))
                .Throws<NotImplementedException>();  
...
Assert.Verify ...
```

Comment: What framework are you using to run your unit tests?  Is this NUnit?

Comment: Is the `[Test]` attribute part of moq?

Comment: nope, nunit ofcourse. rest of this is moq.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to verify that Moq throws an exception? If you want to verify that method was called, you can verify it like this:

```
hotelServiceMock.Verify(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<HotelToCreateDTO>(), true));
```

Comment: nope, this doesnt work. I'm getting Create method takes two arguments.

Comment: sorry, please see edited answer, I have tested this one... assuming your method definition is Create(HotelToCreateDTO, bool)